# How to debug JavaScript in IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Is there a better way to debug JavaScript than MS Script Editor? I am searching for something like Firebug. Firebug Lite doesn't offer this functionality, though.
­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Comment: Is it better javascript tools you need or is more about extra features like DOM inspector?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use Visual Studio 2008.

The Web Development Helper from Nikhilk is useful as is the Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18359). They are not as good as FireBug though :-(

Comment: Agreed this is the best way for debugging JS from within IE.

Comment: Using a raw "debugger" statement in your JavaScript will then allow you to break and jump into VS.

Answer (score 5):

Though not strictly debuggers, these are useful tools for your arsenal

- http://www.debugbar.com/
- http://projects.nikhilk.net/WebDevHelper/

Answer (score 3):

I've used IE WebDeveloper. It's not free and not as nice as Firebug, but got the job done for me. http://www.ieinspector.com/dominspector/index.html

Answer (score 1):

The only other debugger for JavaScript in the IE context is Visual Studio, but it'll cost you. What problems are you having with the script debugger that leads to think you need a better debugger?

I suspect that what you are after are the additional features that aren't specifically about debugging JavaScript but analysing the HTML DOM that has been modified by the JavaScript and the monitoring of the conversation with the server.

The [IE developer toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18359) I find particularly invaluable for debugging web apps as is [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler).

Answer (score 1):

I would try and go for [DebugBar](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/). It's not as nice as Firebug, but it's very useful for javascript debugging...

Answer (score 1):

There is a [blog post](http://notetodogself.blogspot.com/2008/08/debug-javascript-in-ie.html) that goes over most of the known ways to debug javascript in IE, with pros and cons.

Answer (score 1):

Great article mkoryak

I used visual studio web developer as in this linked article
http://www.berniecode.com/blog/2007/03/08/how-to-debug-javascript-with-visual-web-developer-express/

Answer (score 0):

You can download the [Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2008 Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/express/vwd/) for free.

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of Internet Explorer (10.0+ I guess) the developer tools are integrated.

The [debugger panel there](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bg182326%28v=vs.85%29#Tool__Debugger___STRG_3_) allows you to debug your JavaScript like in Firebug, the Firefox DevTools or the Chrome DevTools.