# complete IE failure - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, internet-explorer

I've been working on this for a few days, and have made some (though very little) progress in getting my scripts to work in IE.

FF & Chrome are flawless. Both IE7&8 completely shut-down when running my script. 
The only error I get is when I first load-up the page, and i get a warning that their is an error in the main jquery.min.js page which is being loaded from google. 
I've tried a few different jquery.js, but they all show the same error.

I've put up the page at this address
http://ec2-75-101-196-181.compute-1.amazonaws.com/v2/

The error launches on loading the page, but to get it REALLY to fail, enter a location in the search bar, and then select a result.

I've tried pulling out portions of the script which causes this (jQuery('li.show').click),  and even replaced that entire function(?) with just an alert, and it STILL shutdown IE.

How do you debug something like this? 
I'm using debug bar & microsoft scrip debugger, but as they both show the error being in the main jquery file, it isn't very helpful (i'm quite sure jquery isn't the problem, it must be in my script).

I'm completely lost. Please help...

UPDATE ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

I've managed to track this down to an issue with swfObject and specifically loading the flash vars.

Unfortunately no resolution yet. 
The player URL loads fine,

```
http://lads.myspace.com/videos/Main.swf
```

but adding in the flashvars is what completely kills IE
flashvars u

```
id=-1&pcc=en-US&cc=en-CA&el=http%3a%2f%2fwww.myspace.com%2findex.cfm%3ffuseaction%3duser.viewProfile%26vanity%3djuice&pertid=9415ef45e1d80df9d41f9d2094568ac2&pguid=6817783a34cf42dbbbf5a74054dba4ec&hash=MIGnBgorBgEEAYI3WAOCoIGYMIGVBgorBgEEAYI3WAMBoIGGMIGDAgMCAAECAmYDAgIAwAQI0PAkEoOZrEUEEC0WOKKPFRQTanAktS3u%252fiMEWNtTHsoXrencYJAt%252bXk1hSehTR7tN1iwI1a8vwmEFWmKkRWKkMUgXe2o9o3%252b2B5uxACclT4vkj9X2Q2CXR1cXjCq%252fNCONteEOFyIySkfGEfcZxZD%252frd8gOA%253d&skinid=17&skin=http%3a%2f%2flads.myspacecdn.com%2fvideos%2fartistInternational.xml&isus=false&on=1&afsongs=4&ayt=15&plid=18968&profid=96041003&ptype=4&artid=4791838&pmix=False&shuffle=False&ap=1&t=1&adp=1&mute=false&mt=audio&aftime=300&albid=0&songid=0&amix=false&sindex=-1&sseed=0&nopops=false&ovasin=false&nopomp=false&primarycolor=transparent&secondarycolor=transparent&logerr=false&stime=
```

The code I'm using for the swfObject is

```
params={
                            flashvars: vars
                            };
                    flashvars={};

                swfobject.embedSWF(swfUrl, 'player', '360', '240', '9.0', flashvars, params);
```

2nd Update --------------------------------------------------------------

to resolve this, I've just stuck the swf into an iframe in IE only. Loads that way without errors, but would be nice to do it all in swfObject.

Comment: Stupid question: do you have script debugging enabled in IE? Do you have a script debugger installed?

Comment: If it makes you feel any better, it seems like it's working fine  on IE8 RC1

Comment: Works just fine on the IE build I have and is snappier than Chrome 1.0. :-) You should upgrade to RC1.

Comment: strange, i'm testing in EI8 RC1 with IETester, and that is failing completely as well.

Comment: get rid of the calendar, see if that fixes the problem and go from there

Comment: So there is a way to crash IE7? That's great!

Answer (score 1):

have you tried the [DebugBar](http://www.debugbar.com/?langage=en)? Take a look at [Debugging js in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170164/debugging-javascript-in-ie) post on SO as well.

i'm not sure if you saw my comment - get rid of the calendar popup and see if it fixes the problem

Comment: yes, I have debug bar, but the error that shows is showing as being in the jquery also (unknown runtime error - jquery.1.3.1.js) , not in my script, so it isn't really helping. Great tool though.

Comment: jQuery 1.3 is very young - maybe an upgrade to the latest version (1.3.2) would solve your problems.

Comment: get rid of the calendar on the page ... see if that fixes the error

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is...

1. Install Script Editor from Office
2. Enable Debugging in Internet Options / Advanced
3. Internet Explorer → View / Script Debugger / Open

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome gives an error as well, look into that first?

Comment: the error in chrome is because i've disabled some features. however, everything still works in chrome, and FF,and i had the issue with explorer before i added those features anyway.